# how to let <td> become small?

Tags: css

[image]

How to let td(highlighted) become small ? I try to set witdh equal 50px but cannot show less width

Comment: You should probably show some HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a table you would need to assign each td in every row to 50px if you would  want the whole column to be 50px, otherwise the column will be as wide as the widest td.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `table-layout:fixed` to the table, then the algorithm for determining the width of the cell becomes more straight-forward, and each cell in a column will be set according to the first cell in that column, which will obey value you set for  the width property more strictly.

Otherwise, it the browser determines cell-width by a more complicated algorithm factoring the width of the contents of cells.

see: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/table-layout for more on this property.